# How to break down the Multi Index Above in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have a pivoted data like this

Vendor Id           a                   b
material id   1     2     3       1     2     3
store name

A
B
C

i want it in the format

Vendor Id     a     a     a       b     b     b
material id   1     2     3       1     2     3
store name

A
B
C

in python

i tried copying the names and resetting but it didnt wotk